# Return minimum row wise value with corresponding column value - python

Tags: python

I can return the minimum value across each row. But I'm aiming to return the associated value with the minimum. Below, this is taken from the column directly to the left of the minimum value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Item1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
   'Value1': [1,4,5,7],
   'Item2': ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
   'Value2': [0,4,8,12],
   'Item3': ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N'],
   'Value3': [2.7,3.4,6.2,8.1],
   })

c = ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3']
x, y = range(len(df)), df[c].idxmin(1)

df['Min_Value'] = df.values[x, df.columns.get_indexer_for(y)]
```

intent:

```
  Item1  Value1 Item2  Value2 Item3  Value3 Min_Item  Min_Value
0     A       1     F       0     K     2.7        F        0.0
1     B       4     G       4     L     3.4        L        3.4
2     C       5     H       8     M     6.2        C        5.0
3     D       7     I      12     N     8.1        D        7.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there.  Just convert your `y` Value labels to the corresponding Item labels.

```
>>> yi = y.str.replace('Value', 'Item')
>>> df['Min_Item'] = df.values[x, df.columns.get_indexer_for(yi)]
>>> df
  Item1  Value1 Item2  Value2 Item3  Value3 Min_Value Min_Item
0     A       1     F       0     K     2.7         0        F
1     B       4     G       4     L     3.4       3.4        L
2     C       5     H       8     M     6.2         5        C
3     D       7     I      12     N     8.1         7        D
>>>
```